# Bottle (python) How to display a picture inside a template

Tags: python, image, templates, bottle

i need a very simple exemple to understand theory in the pdf tutorial.

I tried different ways but i always get a symbol meaning lacking picture file.

the text is correctly displayed.

Could you just give me the correct arborescence, files positions, and code for displaying a picture inside a very basic template ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def show_pic():
    picture_name = 'my_picture.png'
    return template('template', picture=picture_name)
```

In template :

```
<img src="path/to/picture/{{picture}}">
```

Don't forget to allow your app serve static files from directory your picture at:

```
@route('/path/to/picture/<picture>')
def serve_pictures(picture):
    return static_file(picture, root='path/to/picture')
```

Comment: Hi , thanks. Here is a good exemple to illustrate with running code:         https://github.com/robotamer/Bottle-tutorial            ===> just cancel validate module which is depreciated             https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bottlepy/5r-KHeZVWFs